# android errno in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Error inserting `pwd=` `user=`

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO table(pwd,user) VALUES (?,?)

> sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table "+"(Tabledata.Tableinfo.user TEXT,Tabledata.Tableinfo.pwd TEXT)");

What is the wrong here please help.

Comment: it seems your query has syntax problem, post your code please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// First, create database
try
{
    // Replace ... with your entities
    db.execSQL("create table myTable (id integer primary key autoincrement, latitude Text,..." );
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Now to save info in database use this code
MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(getBaseContext(), "DataBaseNAme", null, 1);
SQLiteDatabase sql = db.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues gpsData = new ContentValues();
gpsData.put("name", ""); // name is table column name

// At last use this
long result = sql.insert("myTable", "abc", gpsData);

if (result > 0)
{
    // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"data is stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("gps data", "data is store in sqlite");
    sql.close();
    // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"data is saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
    // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Some problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("gps data", "data is not store in sqlite, some error occur");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CREATE TABLE` command is missing the the name of the table.

Every `CREATE TABLE` statement must specify a name for the new table.

Example `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE users
( 
  user TEXT,
  pwd  TEXT
);
```

To insert data into the `users` table using the `INSERT INTO` statement:

```
INSERT INTO users (user, pwd) VALUES ('Paul', 'California');
```

To insert data into the `users` table using SQL Helper:

```
// Gets the data repository in write mode
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

// Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("user", "Paul");
values.put("pwd", "California");

// Insert the new row
db.insert("users", null, values);
```